# Java Client Using OkHttpClient Gzip Compression With WebSphere Liberty

Tags: java, gzip, okhttp, websphere-liberty

We are using WebSphere Liberty 21.0.0.x and Java 11.  We have a main server and we have several microservices that serve data under the covers to the main server. Users will access the UI via the main server URL and no nothing about the microservices under the covers. Today, we have written code in java using OkHttp java libs to make requests to the microservice. Those requests can be GET or POST requests. There is message body data (in the form of json) in either request types and it can get quite large...hence the need for compression.  The responses back can also get quite large. I want to have gzip compression to the microservice and back.

I have enabled compression in WebSphere Liberty following the steps outlined here: https://openliberty.io/blog/2020/04/22/http-response-compression.html
The punchline is add some xml in the server.xml. It's pretty straightforward. Here is the main snippet from my server.xml file:

```
<httpEndpoint host="*" id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443">
        <compression serverPreferredAlgorithm="gzip">
            <types>+application/*</types>
            <types>-text/plain</types>
        </compression>
    </httpEndpoint>
```

My understanding is that is all I need to do on the server side and whatever Content-Encoding the client calls with will be respected by the server.

Here is the client code in java where I am trying to attempt to POST using gzip compression:

```
private static final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
              .addInterceptor(new CompressionInterceptor())
              .readTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
              .writeTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
              .build();

// later in the code
RequestBody jsonRequestBody = RequestBody.create(data, MEDIA_TYPE_JSON);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(urlString)
    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    .post(jsonRequestBody)
    .build();

Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response  response = call.execute();            
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    String responseString = response.body().string();
}
...
```

Here is the GET request code:

```
String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).addHeader("Accept", "application/json").build();
Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response response = call.execute();
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    String someResponse = response.body().string();
}
...
```

Here is the interceptor class that I configured w/ the OkHttpClient instantiation:

```
public class CompressionInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    
    private static final String CONTENT_ENCODING = "Content-Encoding";
    private static final String GZIP = "gzip";

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        if (request.body() == null || request.header(CONTENT_ENCODING) != null) {
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }

        Request compressedRequest = request.newBuilder().header(CONTENT_ENCODING, GZIP)
                .method(request.method(), gzip(request.body())).build();
        return chain.proceed(compressedRequest);
    }

    private RequestBody gzip(final RequestBody body) {
        return new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return body.contentType();
            }

            @Override
            public long contentLength() {
                return -1; // Allow any length
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                BufferedSink gzipSink = Okio.buffer(new GzipSink(sink));
                body.writeTo(gzipSink);
                gzipSink.close();
            }

        };
    }
}
```

I have a couple questions.
a.) I am not sure the above is actually working as intended. Other than a wire shark is there any way I can tell? When I test using a REST Client like Postman I can see that the server response has gzip as part of the headers. However, from the code side, I can't 100% say that it's sending the data as compressed.
b.) I am not sure I have the system properly comfigured/coded for compression both ways. ie, I am not sure that both the request and response are truly compressed.

Comment: For (a) I have personally found tcptunnel to be helpful in these situations.  ( https://github.com/vakuum/tcptunnel ) Basically set tcptunnel to listen on port X and redirect to port Y (that the server is listening on) and it will print the traffic between the two.  You then need to change your client to connect on port X and run the request(s).  That would show you if the headers are added correctly to the request and response.

I don't know about (b), but somebody more familiar with the GZIP compression feature in Liberty should be able to help.

Comment: The Liberty configuration and app code you've put here look right. Are you opposed to using Wireshark? It would be pretty easy (using Wireshark) to validate both a) and b) by looking for a field like _Content-encoded entity body (gzip)_ on the requests and responses.

Comment: I am not opposed to either software.  I have just found that packet sniffers pick up so much traffic (even when you try to capture a small time window) that it becomes a lot to slog through. Fair enough if that is the only and best way.

Comment: Add a networkInterceptor to your application to see exactly what is being sent on the wire.

Comment: @Yuri Schimke - Do you mean another OkHttp Interceptor or a java filter? Can you provide some details? Thx!

Comment: A network interceptor will see the results of your application interceptor on the request, but critically will also see the response before the transparent decompression.  So you can log headers and the first X bytes of the body, look at body.peekBody for this.